# Android Studio-Check value from a variable against data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, ocr

I am new in android programming, currently doing a project about ingredient checking.

My project is supposed scan an ingredient label, and then display whether the ingredient is healthy or non healthy. However, I've only been able to do the scanning(OCR) part at the moment. I tried to compare the extracted text with ingredient data that are already in firebase, but there is no output at all. It just display the extracted ingredient.

Attached below is my code for comparing data.

```
final String dataCompare=sb.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");

DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ingredients").child("iName");

ref.equalTo(dataCompare).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                mStatusEt.setText("Healthy");
                mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            // passcode is present, and is correct
            else{
                mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                mStatusEt.setText("Non-healthy");
                mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            // incorrect passcode or no passcode

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

  //set text to edit text
mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
```

Before trying to compare against data in firebase, i tried the manual dumbest way which look like this

```
/* String dataCompare=sb.toString();

    String b="Flour";

    if (dataCompare.replaceAll("\\s+","").equalsIgnoreCase(b.replaceAll("\\s+",""))){
        mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
        mStatusEt.setText("Healthy");
        mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    else{
        mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
        mStatusEt.setText("Non-healthy");
        mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    //set text to edit text
    mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());*/
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the line `if(dataSnapshot.exists()){` and run the app in a debugger, does it ever reach that breakpoint? If so, what happens when you step through the code from there? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Also: don't ignore potential errors, a minimum `onCancelled` looks like this: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.